# Saving WCF Data to isolated storage and reading it in WP7

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, save, odata, isolatedstorage

How can I store WCF Data or Odata to my WP7 isolated storage and also correctly read these objects later on?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is CTP but its work taking a look considering the title has everything to do with what you asked:

[Accessing WCF Data Services from WP7 CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/03/19/accessing-wcf-data-services-from-wp7-ctp.aspx)

Here's an article on how to save to isolated storage:

[Working With Isolated Storage](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/187702-working-with-isolated-storage/)

Then of course check MSDN:

[How to perform Isolated Storage Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265154%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to hear this but it depends on the data and how you want to access it later.
For instance it may make sense to store the data in a database.

In all likelihood you will probably just want to serialize the response and store it in a  file though. Then to retrieve it, just read from the file and deserialize.